# Create an image from multiple overlapping image parts

Tags: adobe-photoshop, transparency, overlay

I currently have taken pictures of my computer screen playing all of the League of Legends map modes. From there, I have deleted everything but the map itself from each of the images. So now I have of ~13 maps that are overlapping on each other on one PSD. I did this because I wanted to see *where* the maps overlap specifically. I tried making them all 25% opacity and etc but because there are so many maps it looked like a jumbled mess. I could just do that two at a time, but I wanted to know if there was a way to streamline the process.
[Here is the PSD](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1A8K3WqTLPy-t4sjBTycK1wV1SnPD0tJi/view)

Edit: I want the area of all the overlapping maps to be silhouetted, and the parts that are not to be gone. or just the latter

Comment: I want the area of all the overlapping maps to be silhouetted, and the part that's not to be gone. or just the latter

Comment: Do you perhaps have an example you've seen elsewhere you could provide for reference?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/5vqMzAP Here's a post of how I would do it with 2 maps. It gets hard to do it with a lot though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am afraid you need some stronger tools than stacking all shapes and trying to  see possible relations.

Here's one of you shapes traced in illustrator (4 grayshades), the fill is removed and a thin stroke is inserted.

[image]

The result is in the left (no way to remove the doubled lines easily). Making copies with different colors and stacking shows how much visual information you can expect with exact match when only shifting a little makes them fit.

There's only 3 shapes. I believe the task is hopeless if you add 10 more. You must concentrate to less features at the same time. If all at the same time interesting relations are visible in one spesific color, then proceed in color and turn the unwanted colors invisible.

An example of data reduction: If the outermost edges are interesting to be compared, you can extract only them. It's well possible in Photoshop, but this is from Illustrator.

[image]

In Photoshop you can turn your shape to black and detect the edge. As well you can insert layer style "stroke", rasterize and remove the rest.